# coredata after switch to swift 2

Tags: core-data, swift2

i optimize my code to swift 2
now my core data doesn't work correctly.

i think, that my entrie will save, but my tableview do not show any data.
can you find any mistake in the code below?:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Table: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var lm = [LM_ITEMS]()

/*************** DATEN ABRUFEN ***************/
    func DatenAbrufen() {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LM_ITEMS")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [LM_ITEMS]
    } catch { print("Error")}

    Table.reloadData()
}



override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.DatenAbrufen()
}


/*************** ANZAHL DER ZELLEN ERMITTELN ***************/
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return lm.count
}


/*************** ZELLEN MIT INHALT FÜLLEN ***************/
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("lmCell") as! ModifyCells
    let LM_ITEM = lm[indexPath.row]

    cell.name.text = LM_ITEM.name
    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some pretty serious problems.

`DatenAbrufen` executes a fetch request but does not assign the result to anything. You call `executeFetchRequest` but you don't do anything with the result. So, the results are lost, and the fetch serves no purpose.

You declare `lm` as an array but you never put anything into the array. So it's empty, which means that `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` will always return 0-- since `lm.count` will always be 0.

It looks like you probably intended to put the results of the fetch into `lm`.

Comment: thank you vermy much. i forget this line and dont see it the whole time :/

Answer (score 0):

You should move away from using arrays to populate your table view and embrace the `NSFetchedResultsController` API. Check out the Xcode templates. It is the best way to populate a Core Data backed `UITableView`.